# update specific field using switch case using laravel eloquest

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update a specific column using a single API call, its a user journey at various stages in our website. after each stage cross, we have to store his journey.

```
public function updateUserJourney(Request $request){
        var_dump('inside jouney update');
        $journeyObj = UserJourny::find($request->session);
            switch($request){
                case 'details_submitted':
                    $journeyObj->details_submitted = $request->details_submitted;
                    break;
                case 'has_seen_plans':
                    $journeyObj->has_seen_plans = $request->has_seen_plans;
                    break;
                case 'has_compare':
                    $journeyObj->has_compare = $request->has_compare;
                    break;
                case 'has_seen_plan_details':
                    $journeyObj->has_seen_plan_details = $request->has_seen_plan_details;
                    break;      
                case 'has_seen_proposal':
                    $journeyObj->has_seen_proposal = $request->has_seen_proposal;
                    break; 
                case 'submitted_proposal':
                    $journeyObj->submitted_proposal = $request->submitted_proposal;
                    break;    
            }
            $journeyObj->save();
        
        var_dump("field updated");
    }
```

when this function calls, only the session id and one specific field should be updated.
eg, in the request it can be **has_seen_proposal** or **submitted_proposal**.

is there any better way.

i am facing an error `Call to a member function save() on null`

Comment: If $request->session is null UserJourny::find($request->session) will return null, so use findOrFail instead: - UserJourny::findOrFail($request->session). switch statement doesn't seem to get executed the way it's defined.

Comment: okay but is this method correct to update one specific field

Comment: how would `$request` which is an object be equal to the strings of the 'case' statements?

Comment: lagbox, can you please guide me,  i just want to update a specific field. This field will vary in each function call against the same session id.

Comment: how do you know which field to update?

Comment: Why not just send the field you want to update and then you can simply do `$journeyObj->update($request->all())`. Also recommended to use route model binding and skip the use of `find()` in your controller. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way switch statement is written I doubt it gets executed at all. Instead you can

```php
public function updateUserJourney(Request $request)
{
     $userJourny = UserJourny::where('session_id', $request->session_id)
        ->firstOrFail();

     $stages = [
        'details_submitted',
        'has_seen_plans',
        'has_compare',
        'has_seen_plan_details',
        'has_seen_proposal',
        'submitted_proposal',
    ];

    foreach($stages as $stage) {
        if($request->has($stage) && $request->filled($stage)) {
            $userJourny->update([$stage => $request->input($stage)]);
        }
    }

    //Get a fresh copy of the record from database after update
    dd($userJourny->fresh());
}
```

Comment: unexpected ; in `$UserJourny->update([$stage => $request->{$stage}]);`

Comment: i think $request->{$stage} should be $request->stage; if i removed the semicolon it gives an  unexpected '}' at the end oc foreach

Comment: Have updated answer to use $request->input($stage). No it can't be $request->stage, $stage is a variable

Comment: still there is ';' error, sir i think we missing something in syntax

Comment: Have updated answer, had an extra opening parenthesis in the if statement which I have removed now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226156/discussion-between-prathamesh-doke-and-donkarnash).